# Write a Python function of NPTEL online quiz

Tags: python-3.x

Write a Python function maxaggregate(l) that takes a list of pairs of the form (name, score) as an argument, where name is a string and score is an integer. Each pair is to be interpreted as the score of the named player. For instance, an input of the form [('Kohli',73),('Ashwin',33),('Kohli',7),('Pujara',122),('Ashwin',90)] represents two scores of 73 and 7 for Kohli, two scores of 33 and 90 for Ashwin and one score of 122 for Pujara. Your function should compute the players who have the highest aggregate score (aggregate = total, so add up all scores for that name) and return the list of names of these players as a list, sorted in alphabetical order. If there is a single-player, the list will contain a single name.

For instance, maxaggregate([('Kohli',73),('Ashwin',33),('Kohli',7),('Pujara',122),('Ashwin',90)]) should return ['Ashwin'] because the aggregate score of Kolhi is 80, of Ashwin is 123 and of Pujara is 122, of which 123 is the highest.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created a dictionary of players against their aggregate scores, picked out the top run scorers and sorted them with their names.
Here is the code.

```
def maxaggregate(players):

    run_dict = {} #players against runs dictionary
    max_aggregate = 0
    top_run_players = [] #final result array

    #this loop for creating dict of players and their aggregate score
    for player in players:
        if(player[0] in run_dict):
            run_dict[player[0]] += player[1]
        else:
            run_dict[player[0]] = player[1]

    #this loop for inserting the max aggregate score player in top_run_players 

    for player in run_dict:
        if(max_aggregate < run_dict[player]):
            max_aggregate = run_dict[player]
            players.clear()
            players.append(player)
        elif(max_aggregate == run_dict[player]):
            players.append(player)

    #sorting players according to their name
    players.sort()
    return players
```

pass the [('Kohli',73),('Ashwin',33),('Kohli',7),('Pujara',122),('Ashwin',90)] as an input. Btw how can Ashwin have more aggregate than Kohli?